# Google+ API: Get Things I've +1ed

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to fetch all of a user's Google Plus activity. I can get all of a user's [posts](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) but I can't find any way to fetch everything a user have +1ed or commented on. Can I?

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=83) for access to a users +1'd URLs. I did not find a feature request for listing comments from a user but you can request it: http://bugpl.us/new.

Answer (score 1):

use this php code and u get particular activity comment's list

```
$optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
$comments = $plus->comments->listComments(activityid,$optParams);
foreach($comments['items'] as $comment) {
print "{$comment['id']}, {$comment['object']['content']}\n"; 
}
```